# how would i append dropdown html/css to jquery 1 line body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to append dropdown box using html/css. Problem is i have only one id in body, therefore i don't know how to do this. If anyone can post an example for the following code posted, it would be much appreciated.

I foudn something like this but i'm not sure how to set up id's in my code and not sure if this is ok.

```
var someElement = $('<div/>', {id: 'someId'); $('canvas').after(someElement);  $('#someId').doMoreStuff
```

Here is code:

```
    <head>
     <title>jTournament</title>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
     <script src="jTournament.js"></script>

<script>
var matchInfo = {
    "rounds": [{
        "name": "Round1",
            "matches": [{
            "p1": "Bill",
            "p2": "Bob",
            "winner": 1
        }, {
            "p1": "Sam",
            "p2": "Duddly",
            "winner": 2
        }, {
            "p1": "Andy",
            "p2": "Biff",
            "winner": 1
        }, {
            "p1": "Phill",
            "p2": "Peter",
            "winner": 1
        }, {
            "p1": "John",
            "p2": "Dave",
            "winner": 2
        }, {
            "p1": "Xaus",
            "p2": "James",
            "winner": 2
        }, {
            "p1": "Kenny",
            "p2": "Nick",
            "winner": 1
        }, {
            "p1": "Fred",
            "p2": "Pat",
            "winner": 2
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Round2",
        "matches": [{
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }, {
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }, {
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }, {
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Round3",
        "matches": [{
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }, {
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Round4",
        "matches": [{
            "p1": null,
            "p2": null
        }, ]
    }]
};
</script>
    </head
    <body>
 <canvas id="tournament"></canvas>
</body>
```

I'd like to add dropdown menus, so i can connect content dynamically. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new element after canvas using:

```
$('#tournament').after('<div id="newid"></div>');
```

Now if you want to add something 
You can do by using the **append()** function

```
$('#newid').append('<select></select>');
```

Checkout this link if anything else is required http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: i want to replace options with dropdowns

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ 
See this link if for menus.
You can also use lists for this if u want